# How to create a custom command linked to a shortcut in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, command, shortcut

I am looking on how to create a custom command linked to a shortcut in VSCode.
Like so:

```
{
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "-python.execSelectionInTerminal",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"
},
{
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.findNext",
    "when": "terminalFindFocused && terminalProcessSupported"
},
{
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "-python.execSelectionInTerminal",
    "when": "terminalFindFocused && terminalProcessSupported"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create a Task to run the current Python file

**`.vscode/launch.json`**

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    }
  ]
}
```

- Create a keybinding to execute this Task

**`keybindings.json`**

```json
  {
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Python: Current File",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId=='python'"
  }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I am not sure to understand. 
1/ I am not sure why there is 2 "command" lines (maybe for me to add my own in this place?)
2/ When I use your code and run with "shift+enter" it gives me a prompt to "create a task" (not what is expected)
3/ I tried to play with different combination (commenting the 1st "command" line) from your code to use it in an active internal terminal opened at the folder's file location but it prompt a new terminal at the root of the "repo" opened in VSCode

Comment: @Tirbo06 The double `command` was a copy-paste typo

Comment: Ok so finally i updated the topic to your answer as you was partially answering to the question and created another post with a more a precise title, thank you @rioV8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71678016/run-active-python-file-in-active-terminal-or-specific-location-pointing-terminal